# How to fix 404 error in Magento 2 without coding

Tags: redirect, 404

I've deleted some old/discontinued products off the site, and this obviously gives rise to some 404s. How do I redirect these to a category page from the back end of Magento 2. Not a coder so can only do it via the admin panel. Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: I know we're not really supposed to use this as an advertising platform, and I dont. I generally give free advice. However, I wanted to point out that I wrote an extension that does exactly this. https://www.magemodule.com/magento2-extensions/product-redirect/

Comment: There's an url rewrites section in the magento admin in the marketing menu. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Hi, yes, I looked at that ... I forgot to say, I wanted to do it bulk rather then one by one. In Magento 1, you used to be able to it by uploading a csv file via control panel. Can the same be done in Magento 2? If so, what does the file need to look like and where should it be uplaoded? Thanks.